# Do double pendulums violate the law of the conservation of energy?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, energy, energy-conservation, dissipation

When I first saw a double pendulum I thought it was fake because it just doesn't look real the way it moves. Then I searched for more videos and found out that it's real. Can someone explain why they don't violate the law of conservation of energy when they decelerate and accelerate multiple times with no additional energy input.

Here is a video of a double pendulum. This person does little more than just drop them and they move for over 10 minutes and are still moving when the video ends. It seems like the balance between input and output energy is so lop-sided you don't even need to measure it in order to tell that the output is greater than the input.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N6cwXkHxLsU

Answer (score 4):

Strictly speaking, mechanical energy is not conserved because there is air, which dissipates the energy, and the rotating parts are of course not frictionless, so some energy is lost there blablabla. But I suggest you watch this carefully again. Notice how when the pendulums are spinning super quickly, the height of the joint is small, whereas when it rotates slowly, the height is visibly larger.

This is conservation of energy in effect: kinetic energy is converted to gravitational potential energy (slow rotation, large height), and vice-versa (fast rotation, small height). Of course, what I said doesn't prove conservation of energy (for that one has to make precise measurements and make all the necessary calculations, and check if the energy is "approximately conserved" taking into account the above "losses" due to friction). Of course, eventually the oscillations die down, but this is just due to the frictional effects mentioned above.

Comment: Do you know anything else that can decelerate and accelerate with no additional energy input?

Comment: @228 a regular pendulum?

Comment: @228 an ideal spring oscillating back and forth is another example.

Comment: @peek-a-boo The ideal spring is not something that actually exists, right?

Comment: Any spring does it, it needs not be ideal. You will just have additional losses. Springs and pendulums are both approximations of the harmonic oscillator, and many other systems could be cited

Comment: @228 A ball thrown straight up in the air does this.

Answer (score 0):

A double pendulum is a complex mechanical system in which energy flows back and forth between the two arms that form the pendulum. Within each arm, energy also flows back and forth between kinetic energy of rotation and gravitational potential energy. When the geometry is just right, it is possible for almost all the rotational energy in one of the arms to get absorbed by the other arm, causing the one arm to become almost stationary while the other speeds up significantly.

At no time in this process is energy not conserved (although it is easier to *observe* rotational kinetic energy than it is to observe gravitational potential energy), except for small amounts of friction in the pivot bearings and resistance from the air surrounding the penduli.

At https://www.myphysicslab.com/index-en.html, you can play around with an accurate dynamical model of a double pendulum, setting it into motion with any initial conditions you desire, and watching the results. Energy conservation is built into the model.